# How to write time into an IF statement so it recognises it

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This seems like a simple problem but I can't find a solution to it

I have a time sheet which I use for tracking my hours in work.

There is a small IF statement using the following code:

=IF(D5<>FALSE,"7:40", Sheet1!E20)

There is a list of the days with the hours worked and these are summed at the bottom - when the sum is calculated it doesn't seem to read the cell with '7:40' in it - I think this is down the formatting (I have formatted the cell for time using the custom 'hh:mm' which I use for the other cells so I know it works)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution was in my total cell

I was using =SUM(*the range*)

It works when I use =E2+E3+E4+E5+E6